# Zip file as a buffer in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, sharepoint, zip, buffer

I have own SharePoint integration in JavaScript.

For sending files I use endpoint:
`${SITE}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('catalog')/Files/add(url='${fileName}',overwrite=true)`

Everything works properly when I uploaded .jpg and .txt files.
But when I try to upload .zip file, the file in SharePoint is not readable (I had `Error 79 - Inappropriate file type or format`).

Locally (generated by archiver library) this file is correct.

I sending files to SharePoint as a buffer generated by:

```
const buffer = fs.readFileSync(exportedAppDataArchive.pathToFile);
```

I also tried

```
const buffer = fs.readFileSync(exportedAppDataArchive.pathToFile).buffer;
```

and my function to send it to the SharePoint looks like:

```
await axiosInstance.post(fileCollectionEndpoint, arrayBuffer, {
    // responseType: 'buffer',
    headers: {
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
      // 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)',
      Cookie: cookie,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${digest}`,
    },
  });
```

In comments it's my tries with different options...

What is the properly way to send a .zip file as a buffer?